# facing issues for convert from tensorflow core to tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-serving

I am facing issues for convert TensorFlow to TensorFlow Lite. As per research first need to save the model in .pb and by using this file we can convert it into TensorFlow lite but facing an error.

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: Please check https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/ for more info on conversion to tensorflow lite.
Also provide more code examples for a detailed discussion on the focused area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the TF graph representations, exporting as a saved model is recommended. TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model API is more capable than the other conversion APIs. For example, signature def API is only available from the saved model API and there are better support of resource and variant types in the saved model API.

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/exporting_tf2_saved_model
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert

Comment: Thanks for your Ans. I am working on project and use posnet library by using this library write some code and facing issue to convert that code also into tflite but not able to do.